# Set an environment variable that affects a whole compound command

Tags: bash, environment-variables

How can I set a one-shot variable that affects an entire compound command?

E.g., something like:

```
FOO=1 ./foo.sh && ./foo.sh
```

where `foo.sh` contains `echo "FOO=$FOO"` will print:

```
FOO=1
FOO=
```

I would like the value of `FOO` to be set for entire pipeline (but I don't want to set or export it in my current shell). A subshell works:

```
( export FOO=1; ./foo.sh && ./foo.sh )
```

... but is there a way w/o a subshell?

Comment: "Compound command line" might describe your examples better than "pipeline", as the current examples don't have any pipes.

Comment: I assume, since you didn't say, that `FOO=1 ./foo.sh && FOO=1 ./foo.sh` is unacceptable?

Comment: Thanks @JeffSchaller - yes, "compound command" is more accurate: I've updated it.  I mean it's not "unacceptable" necessarily but I was trying to avoid it (yes, I am aware that I could repeat it like that). The actual command line has more than two commands, and I want to quickly change one `FOO` to change it in all of them. The subshell works OK I guess, just wondering if there was a syntax I was missing.

Answer (score 2):

The subshell approach would be the approach with less typing:

```sh
(
    export FOO="value"
    ./foo.sh && ./foo.sh
)
```

The other way to do it would be through starting a child shell and set the environment variable for that shell:

```sh
FOO="value" sh -c './foo.sh && ./foo.sh'
```

Other variations are to explicitly set the variable for each invocation of your script, as in

```sh
FOO="value" ./foo.sh &&
FOO="value" ./foo.sh
```

which could be made slightly more convenient with

```bash
foo=( env FOO="value" ./foo.sh )
"${foo[@]}" && "${foo[@]}"
```

or, with `/bin/sh`,

```sh
set -- env FOO="value" ./foo.sh
"$@" && "$@"
```

Or you may set it in the calling script and then unset it once you're done with it, as in

```sh
export FOO="value"
./foo.sh && ./foo.sh
unset FOO
```

Answer (score 1):

What you ask is something not achievable without any hacks done. The reason is when you run the script with

```
FOO=1 ./foo.sh && ./foo.sh
```

you are basically launching two separate instances of shell which inherit all the traits (variables) from the parent shell you launched this on. If you print the `$$` variable inside the `foo.sh` you will notice separate proc-ids for each of the scripts started.

Now `FOO=1` in the first part only affects the environment started by the first process. The variable is *not* even available in the parent shell launched on, but only in the scope of the first process. There is *no* way this variable set can be reflected on the environment of the second process which runs on a separate user-space altogether.

There is no way this second process sees this value in its environment unless the value is inherited from its parent ( when the variable is explicitly exported from the shell the pipeline is run ) or the value is passed again locally to the second script.